# Accepting a positive integer from either a command-line argument or System.in

Tags: java, performance, validation, console

I've been doing a lot of programs for classes that require a prompt from the program. I thought it would be much faster for me to rapidly test inputs if I didn't have to execute the program and then type the input once inside the program (as opposed to just hitting <kbd>↑</kbd> and adjusting the input that way).

My concern is this code seems to have some duplication with the exception handling, and I'm also not sure if it's as efficient as it can be. I'm somewhat of a beginner, but I'm certainly interested in more advanced ideas/solutions as that would point in direction of where to self-study more.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 *  This program is to implement testing command line input or reverting to regular prompts if
 *  an argument isn't provided or is invalid. It tests to see if the input is a negative integer,
 *  and displays the result.
 *
 *  Algorithm:
 *  If the console argument is valid, treat it as user input, or otherwise ignore it
 *  Continue to ask for a positive integer until one is given.
 *  Display the integer given and confirm it's negative
 */
public class TestConsoleArgs
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String arg;
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;

        try {
            arg = args[0];
            num = Integer.parseInt(arg);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            arg = "";
        } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
            arg = "";
        }

        while (num <= 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Please type in a positive integer.  ");
            arg = user_input.next();

            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(arg);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.print("That's not an integer! ");
                continue;
            }

            if (num <= 0)
            {
                System.out.print("That's a negative number. ");
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Yes, '" + num + "' is a positive integer.");
    }
}
```

Comment: "I thought it would be much faster for me to rapidly test inputs if I didn't have to execute the program and then type the input once inside the program (as opposed to just hitting the up arrow and adjusting the input that way)." Are you perhaps looking for a way to do [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) as well? A well-written method signature instead of 'doing everything' inside a `main()` method  will be of some help too...

Comment: @h.j.k. I hadn't heard of unit testing before, although after reading the article, I guess that's kind of what I'm doing here. I'm mostly just focusing on how to best read and (safely) use input from the command line, which I intend to use elsewhere. The particular idea of testing to see if it's a positive number was just the simplest thing I thought of arbitrarily. Regarding factoring, I'm also not really sure how I'd be able to do that usefully in this case.

Comment: Command line args are better than stdin prompts for scriptable programs, but you could solve you problem with `echo foo | java MyClass`.  Or `java MyClass <<< "some string"`, to make the interactive up-arrow cmdline editting slightly easier.  (ctrl-a beginning of line, alt-d delete forward word would set you up for typing a new "foo" if you're using a terminal & shell with nice cmdline editing, e.g. bash.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231671/79808 for more tips.  These should work in a cygwin terminal in Windows, too, and maybe even mingw.)

Comment: BTW, strictly speaking, 0 is neither a positive or negative number. Similar to your solution, I've made an assumption [in my answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105878/27975) but I treat it as positive. YMMV. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the variable name `arg`, `input` or `argument` would be preferred due to clarity and distinct nature from the conventional `args` in the main method.

You're over-complicating things, you can eliminate the need to check array bounds by evaluating and running based on `args.length`.

Here's a simple example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Add {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 2) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Result: " + 
                    (Double.parseDouble(args[0]) + Double.parseDouble(args[1]))
                );
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {/*Proceed*/}
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print(
            "Simple example- adding two numbers\n"
            + "Enter the first number: "
        );
        double alpha = validate(input);

        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        double beta = validate(input);

        System.out.println("The result is " + (alpha + beta));
        input.close();
    }

    private static double validate(Scanner input) {
        String userEntry = input.next();

        while (!isNumber(userEntry)) {
            System.out.print("Not a number, enter again: ");
            userEntry = input.next();
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(userEntry);
    }

    private static boolean isNumber(String input) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(input);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If the user gives the *expected length* of  *valid* input run the shorter version. Otherwise, run through the program, including the error checking.

Comment: This is easily breakable if a user wants to be silly and enter a letter, which is what I was trying to prevent. If the user types **java Add d f** from the command line, they get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "d
"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)

Comment: Understood. I've edited it to give you more ideas, try again.

Answer (score 3):

`user_input` can be better renamed as `userInput`.

If you want to make the prompting 'self-contained', put it inside a method that will re-prompt the user for non-integer values:

```
private static int getIntegerInput(Scanner scanner) { ... }
```

I also don't think you need to catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, instead consider picking up from the command line *only if* `args.length` is at least 1:

```
// calls getIntegerInput(Scanner) with scanner if input is not an integer
private static int parseStringOrPrompt(String input, Scanner scanner) { ... }
```

Putting it altogether:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int num = args.length > 0 ? parseStringOrPrompt(args[0], scanner) 
                                    : getIntegerInput(scanner);
        while (num < 0) {
            System.out.print("That's a negative integer.");
            num = getIntegerInput(scanner);
        }
        System.out.println("Yes, '" + num + "' is a positive integer.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using try-with-resources on a `Scanner` with `System.in` will close `System.in` at the end of the block. That may not be desired.

Comment: @Johnbot right, it should only be done in the `main()` method.